# abide law — how to say and generalization

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

1. Suppose that some algebraic operations $+$ and $\oplus$ satisfy the abide
   law, i.e. $(a_0+a_1)\oplus(b_0+b_1)=(a_0\oplus b_0)+(a_1\oplus b_1)$. How
   should I say this, “$+$ abides by $\oplus$” or what?
2. Is there a generalization of the abide law for any arity, i.e. $f(g(a_{00}, a_{01}, \ldots), g(a_{10}, a_{11}, \ldots), \ldots)$ $= g(f(a_{00}, a_{10}, \ldots), f(a_{01}, a_{11}, \ldots), \ldots)$?

Comment: You should specify some context for the abide law, e.g. perhaps you are working with streams in functional programming languages, e.g. see Hinze: [Concrete Stream Calculus.](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/publications/CSC.pdf)

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: Why? It's odd that we use different words in different contexts for the same concept.

Answer (score 1):

(1) The authors of [these notes on polynomial relators](https://alexandria.tue.nl/extra1/wskrap/publichtml/199110.pdf) would say that ‘$+$ abides $\oplus$’. However, the two operations appear symmetrically, a fact that is better reflected in the usages ‘$+$ and $\oplus$ abide’, ‘$+$ and $\oplus$ are abiding operations’ (as found [here](http://comonad.com/reader/2008/just-fokkinga-abide/) and [here](https://pozorvlak.livejournal.com/103349.html), for instance). However, the terminology seems to depend somewhat on the mathematical context: in category theoretic contexts I’ve seen this as ‘$+$ and $\oplus$ satisfy the interchange (or exchange) law’, e.g. [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180901071549/http://planetmath.org:80/interchangelaw) and in Saunders MacLane, [*Categories for the Working Mathematician*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categories_for_the_Working_Mathematician). (This terminology is also mentioned in the notes on polynomial relators.)

(2) If $f$ and $g$ are $n$-ary operations for some $n$, the condition that$$f(g(a_{11},\dots,a_{1n}),\dots,g(a_{n1},\dots,a_{nn})) = g(f(a_{11},\dots,a_{n1}),\dots,f(a_{1n},\dots,a_{nn}))$$for all $n\times n$ matrices $[a_{ij}]$ for which the expressions are defined is certainly meaningful, but I have no idea whether it has found any use when $n>2$.

Comment: Actually, $f$ and $g$ may have different arity. @Brian M. Scott: